# Not able to access cookie in javascript at path /

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using jQuery to access/set the cookies. I have planted a cookie named `CookieNo1` at path `/`.

I planted this using the url `localhost:8080/audi`.

The cookie value is stored, which I checked manually on the firefox cookies. Now when I try to access the same cookie, using the url `localhost:8080/audi/products` using `$.cookie('CookieNo1');`

This doesn't seem to retrieve the value of the cookie. It returns a null value. However when I try to write the cookie using the same `localhost:8080/audi/products` url, it overwrites the previous cookie value. Please help me with this issue.

All I need is `$.cookie('CookieNo1')` to return the previous cookie value instead of null. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Maxim that's one cookie issue. There isn't a problem with the url path as you might have thought because cookies are stored per domain and will be sent for each request from anything originating from that domain.could you check what `document.cookie` returns on this url `http://localhost:8080/audi/products`

Comment: @BookOfZeus Yes I am using jquery, added that in the question too

Comment: @MaximDsouza I just saw it ;) did you try adeno solution?

Comment: @Deeptechtons document.cookie returns JSESSIONID=C987E73F47D5DB2C503B4652166C5F58

Comment: @BookOfZeus Adeno didnt give any solution. var getmycookie = $.cookie("mycookie");
 returns null for me when accessed from the url `http://localhost:8080/audi/products`, when the cookie was planted using `http://localhost:8080/audi`

Comment: @RobW I add the cookie using jquery on the page `http://localhost:8080/audi` with the code `$.cookie("asdftraffic", valueToSet, { expires: 30, path: '/', secure: true });` I try to retrieve the cookie from the url `http://localhost:8080/audi/products` using '$.cookie('asdftraffic');' which returns null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the expiry date. Otherwise, the cookie is removed at the end of the session. In JQuery: `$("CookieNo1", "value", {expires: 7})` (this cookie stays for 7 days).

In JavaScript:

```
document.cookie = "CookieNo1=value; max-age=604800";
```

`max-age` sets the maximum lifetime of a cookie, in seconds.

## EDIT

Quote from comments:

> @RobW I added the cookie using jquery on the page
>   http://localhost:8080/audi with the code `$.cookie("asdftraffic",
>   valueToSet, { expires: 30, path: '/', secure: true });` I try to
>   retrieve the cookie from the url http://localhost:8080/audi/products
>   using `'$.cookie('asdftraffic');'` which returns null.

Your issue is caused by `secure: true`. This attribute requires the cookie to be transmitted over a secure connection (`https`). Remove the `secure: true` flag if you're not using an encrypted connection.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I want to access the cookie at path / from the url localhost:8080/audi/products

Comment: @MaximDsouza COL, cookies are saved per domain Does `http://localhost:8080` and `http://localhost:8080/audi/products` look like different domains to you??

Comment: @Deeptechtons When did I say they are of different domains. They are on the same domain, but the cookie planted by the /audi url isnt accessible on /audi/products url.

Comment: **Your cookies aren't accessible from other paths because they expire when your page unloads**. Is that clear?

Comment: @MaximDsouza well this meant it `This is not what I am looking for. I want to access the cookie at path / from the url localhost:8080/audi/products`. anyway did you try setting expiration time and checking it again?

Comment: @RobW I am not trying to access the cookie from the different path like a cookie on /bar from /foo. I am trying to access a cookie at path / from a path /xyz which ideally should work. And the expiration time didnt help as well..it was added before itself...

Comment: Before I can help any further, at least show the relevant code.

Comment: @RobW I added the cookie using jquery on the page `http://localhost:8080/audi` with the code `$.cookie("asdftraffic", valueToSet, { expires: 30, path: '/', secure: true });` I try to retrieve the cookie from the url `http://localhost:8080/audi/products` using '$.cookie('asdftraffic');' which returns null.

Answer (score 1):

First you set the cookie:

```
var myvalue = 100, 2000, 300;
$.cookie("mycookie", myvalue);
```

Then you get the cookie:

```
var getmycookie = $.cookie("mycookie");
    var myvalues = getmycookie.split(",");
    var firstval = myvalues[0];
    var secondval = myvalues[1];
    var thirdval = myvalues[2];
```

Should'nt be much harder.
When not specifying an expiration, the cookie is deleted on session end i.e. when the browser is closed.

EDIT: You can also specify the path:

```
$.cookie("mycookie", myvalue, {
expires : 10,           //expires in 10 days

path    : '/products',          //The value of the path attribute of the cookie 
                       //(default: path of page that created the cookie).

domain  : 'http://localhost:8080',  //The value of the domain attribute of the cookie
                       //(default: domain of page that created the cookie).

secure  : true          //If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
                       //will be set and the cookie transmission will
                       //require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
});
```

I would think something like this would do:

```
var myvalue = 100, 2000, 300;
$.cookie("mycookie", myvalue, {path : '/audi/products'});
```

Oh, and a session ends when the browser is closed, not when the page is unloaded, so a session cookie will do.

Comment: `var getmycookie = $.cookie("mycookie");` returns null for me when accessed from the url `http://localhost:8080/audi/products`, when the cookie was planted using `http://localhost:8080/audi`